# How can I calculate metrics on a spat raster based on a known year? ex: dNBR

Tags: r, function, raster, metrics, terra

"I am trying to calculate a number of metrics that describe spectral recovery post-fire across a time series. I have a 'spatraster' of fitted NBR values over 38 years (export of LandTrendR) on my AOI and the year of the fire.

```
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 967, 1193, 38  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 8.983153e-05, 8.983153e-05  (x, y)
#extent      : -115.5009, -115.3937, 51.15043, 51.2373  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : NBR_FTV_fit_neg_stack.tif 
#names       : 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, .
 
year_of_fire == 2014
```

One simple metric I would like to calculate is dNBR, where:
dNBR=NBR pre −NBR post
​
I am attempting to write a function that calculates this using 'year_of_fire,' which is just a year I have saved as a variable.

I want to create a function that indexes the 'spatraster' layers based on 'year_of_fire' without manually passing the pre and post-fire years, as I will need to run this on dozens of fires.

I believe I will need to use the 'tapp::terra' package to get the output raster of the calculated metric (in this case, dNBR).

[for context; I am trying calculate a handful of metrics that all use year_of_fire;
R80P (ratio of recovery @80 percent) = Max(year 4 or 5) post fire / NBR pre3 (avg of 3 years pre fire)*.8

Appreciate any thoughts on alternatives.

I have tried to use tapp but have not been successful at figuring out how to tell the function to index based on year_of_fire.

Comment: Hi user217532, welcome to SO. It will make it much easier to answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). For you, a minimal example would most likely mean making a subset of your spatraster which has the minimum amount of data required to reproduce what you want to achieve. Then, run `dput()` on the data you are using e.g. `dput(my sample spatraster)`, and copy the result into your question. Also, add the code you have tried into a codeblock. Thanks

Comment: You cannot use `dput` with SpatRasters, but there are very many examples on this site and in the help file that show how you can create example data with code or use a file that ships with R.

Answer (score 0):

You should improvide your question, provide some example data, and be as specific as possible. But here is a start. With SpatRaster `nbr` you could do

```
years <- as.integer(names(nbr))
i <- which(years == year_of_fire)

dNBR <- nbr[i-1] − nbr[i+1]​
R80P <- max(nbr[[ i+4:5 ]]) / mean(nbr[[ (i-4):(i-1) ]])
```

Comment: Thank you for this - so simple - I was very much overthinking it.